# "help identifying" or "in identifying"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have the following sentence which contains couple of sentences that I have doubts in, namely:

> the classification has the potential for serving as a useful tool in
>   devising a usability guidelines compliance assessment model which can
>   enable ranking the websites usability that help identifying the
>   websites that require more attention to improve them

- `website usability` or `websites usability`
- `help identifying` or `help in identifying`
- `to improve` or `to improve them`

Comment: Your sentence has quite a few grammatical errors, but we don't do proofreading here.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I do not need your answer. But what I posted is called a question which is an essential part of the learning process. I am not sure if you are aware that this forum is called "language learners". Proofreading is when I post some text and ask for picking the mistakes. In my case I am hesitated in couple of choices. I am sure there are lots of people who are happy to help non natives to improve their english and learn through practice which involve asking questions.

Comment: The rule here is to ask one question, mainly so that judging the answer is simpler.  Please edit your question to ask about one thing, and feel free to post separate questions about each of your concerns. And you did not ask a question.  You said "I have a sentence which contains...sentences that I have doubts in".